# How to limit style to component level in React?

Tags: css, reactjs

My app tries to show emails. Sometimes the style in the email will affect the app itself.

Right now I am using the package [juice](https://github.com/Automattic/juice) to inline style in the email html. However, sometimes it cannot inline correctly. So I try to find other solutions.

I know Angular automatically add some random string in each class to make sure style in one component won't affect other component, is there a same way to do it in React? Or is there other way to limit style to the component level without using iframe? Thanks

The demo shows the `p { color: red; }` from the email also affects the app itself. In this case, it affects `Content in app`.

<kbd>[Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-gqhheg?file=index.js)</kbd>

```
class Mail extends Component {
  render() {
    // the style inside is from mail, in real case, it can have tens or even hundreds of different styles
    const mailFromServer = `
      <html>
        <head>
          <style>
            p { color: red; }
          </style>
        </head>

        <body>
          <p>Content in mail</p>
        </body>
      </html>
    `;

    return (
      <div>
        <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: mailFromServer}} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Mail />

        <p>Content in app</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are few ways to do this.One of the way would be by passing `style` to the elements and defining styles as objects. For example

```
const styles = {
        content: {
            color: '#000',
            backgroundColor: '#fafafa',
        },
    };

class Mail extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return() {
            <p style={{styles.content}}> Content </p>
        }
    }
}
```

If you really want something scalable then you can use [styled-components](https://www.styled-components.com/) which for me personally work really nicely and fulfills all your styling needs.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a class to limit the style to a specific component's features:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

class Mail extends Component {
  render() {
    const mail = `
      <html>
        <head>
          <style>
            .mail-header { color: red; }
          </style>
        </head>

        <body>
          <h1 class="mail-header">Heading in mail</h1>
        </body>
      </html>
    `;

    return (
      <div>
        <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: mail}} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Mail;
```

Comment: Thanks, however, the email is from server, and it usually has tens or even hundreds of styles, it is hard to edit them manually easily.

Answer (score 0):

Styles in `<style>..</style>` or from CSS sheet is global. They are applied across your app.

If you have control over how the email is formatted, I would recommend setting different class names for different email types.

If you have a limited set of email types, you can specify the styles for each of them in a css sheet, and import it on your html file or Webpack.

`styles.css`

```
.important-email { color: red; }
.not-important-email { color: blue; }
// ...
// styles for different email types
```

`Mail.jsx`

```
class Mail extends Component {
  render() {
    const mail = `
      <html>
        <head>
        </head>

        <body>
          <h1 class="important-email">Heading in mail</h1>
        </body>
      </html>
    `;

    return (
      <div>
        <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: mail}} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Mail;
```

Comment: Thanks. But my question mentions the style is from mail, and it is very hard to edit each mail style manually especially when you don’t know what styles inside.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use CSS Modules, which is one or more css files (written in js) in which all class names are auto-scoped locally to each component by default.

There is a good article about this here https://medium.com/@pioul/modular-css-with-react-61638ae9ea3e

You can also try to reset those known html entities which are commonly over-ridden by your Mail html. You may have to play around a bit, but, given your example, you could do something like the following:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-neymbb

Basically, in my sandbox I reset your paragraph color and padding to their defaults, as well as, used it in conjunction with another inline style. Depending on the entire construct of css inheritance in your app, your results may vary, but you should be able to get something workable.

More information on the css values I recommend found here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial

Comment: I was thinking you could use that along w/ some basic "reset" styling.  Cover the obvious over-stylings by using `initial`, `inherit`, `unset`, or `revert` on those known rules that are interfering w/ your component.

Comment: Hmm, sorry I didn’t get it. I might don’t know some style knowledge here. Would you mind providing some codes in the answer? Thanks

Comment: @HongboMiao will something like that work? Or are you needing a different approach?

Comment: I will check soon when I back to my computer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Even though [browser support](https://caniuse.com/?search=%40scope) is not great (**48%**) at the moment for [@scope](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-cascade-6/#scoped-styles), it can be used to *selectively* target ancestor subtrees. For example, [in this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/CSSBurner/cjxtg2nh/) (please run in Chrome November 2023 due to browser support limitations), you can see that the `.target` sub-tree is selected for:

```
p {
    color: red;
    font-size: 24px
}

@scope (.target) {
    p {
        color: green
    }
}
```

In your demo case above, try using `@scope` like this:

```
class Mail extends Component {
    render() {
        const mailFromServer = `
            <html>
                <head>
                    <style>
                        @scope (.target) { // added @scope
                            p { color: red; }
                        } 
                    </style>
                </head>
                <body class=target> <!-- added scoping class -->
                    <p>Content in mail</p>
                </body>
            </html>`;
        return (
           <div>
               <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: mailFromServer}} />
           </div>
        );
    }
}
```